# explain this virtual function pointer code?

Tags: c++, function-pointers

```
#include <iostream>

struct Shape
{
    virtual Shape* duplicate() { return new Shape; }
    virtual void print() { std::cout << "SHAPE" << std::endl; }
    virtual ~Shape() {}
};

struct Box : public Shape
{
    virtual Box* duplicate() { return new Box; }
    virtual void print() { std::cout << "BOX" << std::endl; }
};

int main(int argc, char** argv) 
{ 
  Shape* s1 = new Box;
  Box* b1 = s1->duplicate();

  b1->print();

  delete s1;
  delete b1;

  return 0; 
}
```

I am not sure if this is the syntax of  a function pointer and if it is even then the main function is confusing... moreover pointer is being used while object declaration.. i am not familiar with such declaration so please explain how this code works..???

Comment: I don't see any function pointers. If it's `virtual` that's confusing you, read the appropriate chapter of a book or find a good article on the matter.

Comment: sidenote: typically, create and destroy objects in LIFO order, not in FIFO order

Comment: Or do that automatically with a smart pointer.

Comment: if there is no  function pointer thn what does shape* duplicate() mean..?? @chris

Comment: @MragankYadav, Applying the [spiral rule](http://c-faq.com/decl/spiral.anderson.html), `duplicate` is a function returning a pointer to a `Shape`. If you need a pointer to a function returning a `Shape`, it's `Shape (*duplicate)()`, which can again have the spiral rule successfully applied to it to read as such.

Comment: @MragankYadav: I fyou don't know anything about virtual functions, new and delete, then why are you using them? Your problem is not understanding function pointers. Your problem is that you are using C++ facilities without being familiar with them. Serious advice is to get a good C++ book, which your typical C++ guru has many of.

Comment: Argh, the quality of this sunday morning's questions is fascinating and does not quite motivate me to provide useful answers. Voting for close.

Answer (score 1):

The following defines a virtual function that takes no arguments and returns a pointer to `Shape`:

```
struct Shape
{
    virtual Shape* duplicate() { return new Shape; }
```

The following *overrides* this function

```
struct Box : public Shape
{
    virtual Box* duplicate() { return new Box; }
```

Notice how the return type is changed to `Box*`. This is permissible because `Box` is a subclass of `Shape`. This is called [covariant return types](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariant_return_type).

The following attempts to call `Box::duplicate()` via a `Shape*` pointer:

```
  Shape* s1 = new Box;
  Box* b1 = s1->duplicate();
```

This won't compile because `Shape::duplicate()` returns `Shape*` and not `Box*`.